# How do I set the current year in my Select as default in Reactive Forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

Hello I have created a select which shows me the current year, the 5 years from the past and 3 years from the future. Now I would like to set it so that the current year is always the default. This should be done in Reactive Forms... Do you know how to do that?

My Code:

```
// HTML
<form [formGroup]="sendYearsForm">
<select class="upload_slc" id="upload_slc" required title="" formControlName="year" 
 (change)="sendYear($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let years of sendYears" [value]="years">{{years}}</option>
</select>
 <div class="select_arrow"></div>
</form>
```

```
// TS
sendYearsForm: FormGroup;
currentDate: Date = new Date();
selectedYear: number;

// Year form
    this.sendYearsForm = this.fb.group({
      year: [null]
    });
    // Show the current year with -5 and +3
    this.selectedYear = this.currentDate.getFullYear(); // HThe current year is transferred here. How do I integrate it into the template?
    for (let i = this.currentDate.getFullYear() - 5; i <= this.currentDate.getFullYear() + 3; i++) {
      this.sendYears.push(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use patchValue to change the value of a formcontrol

**yourFormGroupName.controls.yourFormControlName.patchValue(value you want to assign)**

In your case

```
this.sendYearsForm = this.fb.group({
  year: [null]
});
// Show the current year with -5 and +3
this.selectedYear = this.currentDate.getFullYear(); // The current year is transferred here. How do I integrate it into the template?

this.sendYearsForm.controls.year.patchValue(this.selectedYear); // this will set the value of 'year' control to selectedYear(current year)

for (let i = this.currentDate.getFullYear() - 5; i <= this.currentDate.getFullYear() + 3; i++) {
  this.sendYears.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one of the following ways:

```js
this.selectedYear = this.currentDate.getFullYear();
this.sendYearsForm= this.fb.group({
  year: new FormControl(this.selectedYear, [])
});
```

or

```js
this.sendYearsForm = this.fb.group({
 year: [null]
});
this.selectedYear = this.currentDate.getFullYear();
this.sendYearsForm.get('year').setValue(this.selectedYear);
```